# Load CSV from local machine into spark which is running on Docker

Tags: scala, docker, apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to load a CSV file from my local drive into Spark but it throws **"org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file: /somepath/export.csv"**.

Here is my code in Scala:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Test App")
  .master("spark://10.5.0.2:7077")
  .getOrCreate()

val schema = new StructType()
  .add("_c0",IntegerType,true)
  .add("carat",DoubleType,true)
  .add("cut",StringType,true)
  .add("color",StringType,true)
  .add("clarity",StringType,true)
  .add("depth",DoubleType,true)
  .add("table",DoubleType,true)
  .add("price",IntegerType,true)
  .add("x",DoubleType,true)
  .add("y",DoubleType,true)
  .add("z",DoubleType,true)

val df = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("file:///somepath/resources/diamond.csv")
spark.close()
```

Comment: mount the volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a bind mount in docker. For example, to make the folder /Users/JohnSmith/somedata available to spark under the folder /mnt/somedata you would start your image as follows:

```
docker run -v /Users/JohnSmith/somedata:/mnt/somedata myimage
```